# Measure theory properties proof

Tags: measure-theory

For a set $A \subset \mathbb R$, $\alpha \in \mathbb R$ and $x_o \in \mathbb R$, put

$x_0 + A:=${$x_o+a:a \in A$} and $\alpha A:=${$\alpha a:a \in A$}

Let $m^*$ be an outer measure on a set $X=[a,b]$ and $A$ be a set such that $x_o+A\subset X$ and $\alpha A \subset X$. Show that

$m^*(x_o+A)=m^*(A)$ and $m^*(\alpha A) = |\alpha|m^*(A)$.

I'm having trouble with these outer measure properties and understanding these proofs. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Probably you can show it by using the definition of outer measure in terms of coverings by intervals, with the observation that translating or scaling an interval still results in an interval.

Answer (score 5):

Let´s prove that outer measure is translation invariant. Without loss of generality.
Let $\{I_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be any countable collection of open intervals, which covers A iff $\{I_n+x_{0}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$  covers $A+x_{0}$. Furthermore, note that 
$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}l(I_{k})= \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}l(I_{k}+x_{0})$ (where l is the lenght of the interval).
From the last two observation it follows that outer measure is translation invariant. 
Since the infimum is unique, and $m^{*}(A)$ and $m^{*}(A)$ are the infima of the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}l(I_{k})$ and $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}l(I_{k}+x_{0})$, respectively.
Now for the second part note that there is a factor $\alpha \in\mathbb{R}$ multiplying the lenght of each interval in your cover.  $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}l(\alpha I_{n})=|\alpha|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}l(I_{n})$. Then you need to note that the infimum of such series is $|\alpha|m^{*}(A)$ .

Comment: Let $\alpha$ be a real number. And let $I=(a,b)$ Then $l(\alpha I)= |\alpha b-\alpha a|=|\alpha|l(I)$.